# Is it possible to point a location to go with Here Drive?

Tags: here

Sometimes when you want to go to some place you know it in "*that street after more 100 meters"* but you don't know exactly what is the place number.

I know I can search for "*145 west 44 street Manhattan*" but supposedly I don't know the number but can find it on the map how can I ask **Here Drive** "*go to this place in my finger*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Here Maps. Touch the place you want to go, then touch the blue arrow to get directions. (If you subsequently want to use the same position again, it will be in your "Recent" collection.)

Comment: Don't understand why the don't have just one app with all features.